# extracting values from many sequentially labeled dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate mean values of a specific column from many similarly formatted dataframes, which are named dataframe_1 - dataframe_100. I have been trying a for loop as below:

```
mean=[]
dfnum = range(1,101)
for i in dfnum:
    var=('dataframe_'+str(i))
    mean1=var.column.mean()
    mean.append(mean1)
```

I am hoping to end up with a list of 100 means, 1 for each dataframe/column.

However I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'column'
```

Comment: That's because you have not loaded the dataframes. how are they stored? you should use something like `pd.read_csv(var)` instead.

Comment: @Tabaraei I fear OP has the variables `dataframe_1` to `dataframe_100` in the local scope.

Comment: Provided the dataframes exist: You could replace `var=('dataframe_'+str(i))` with `exec('var = dataframe_' + str(i))` and then it should work. But that's not a good way. Better organize your frames in a list and then iterate over it to process the frames.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the variables `dataframe_1` to `dataframe_100` in the local scope, you can try to replace the line `var=('dataframe_'+str(i))` with the following:

```
var = locals()['dataframe_'+str(i)]
```

If the variables are in global scope, you can use:

```
var = globals()['dataframe_'+str(i)]
```